# How can I add a safeTransferFrom royalty/fee to the Contract Owner?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, fees, erc-1155, royalties

I have created a contract implementing ERC2981 and ERC1155, however I am not being able to understand how can I take a, eg. 5%, fee each time tokens change owners.

I am using openzeppelin implementation of ERC1155, which contains the following:

```
    /**
     * @dev See {IERC1155-safeTransferFrom}.
     */
    function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 id,
        uint256 amount,
        bytes memory data
    ) public virtual override {
        require(
            from == _msgSender() || isApprovedForAll(from, _msgSender()),
            "ERC1155: caller is not owner nor approved"
        );
        _safeTransferFrom(from, to, id, amount, data);
    }
```

What do I need to change to allow charging a fee of 5% of the value the NFT is being sold, and still be compliant with the ERC1155 standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please note that it is always possible for somebody to avoid the fee. The "official" transfer is reported as "$0" and then actual money changes hands outside the system.

Anybody who has sold a car or a house understands the incentive to underreporting the value of a transaction.

---

In general, the only way to collect a fee is to also control the movement of money, and that means making a marketplace.

You probably don't want to make a marketplace.